# Probability of rolling doubles on different numbers of d6 dice when 6 doesn't count?

Tags: probability

So I've been playing a game where you roll standard 6 sided dice and look for doubles. The number of dice you roll varies between 2 and 8 in this game and every number inbetween those could be rolled. Double 6 does not count as a success. What is the probability of rolling any double, except a double six with 2 dice, 3 dice, 4 dice, 5 dice, 6 dice, 7 dice and 8 dice?

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?

Comment: See [Probability of rolling doubles from 5 dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042367) and [Rolling two doubles with 4 and 5, 6 sided dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281375)

Answer (score 0):

The probability to get doubles with $n$ dice is calculated at [Probability of rolling doubles from 5 dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042367) as

$$
1-6^{-n}\frac{6!}{(6-n)!}\;.
$$

In your case, we also need to exclude double sixes. We can do this by summing over the number $k$ of $6$s contained in the roll. There are $\binom nk$ ways to choose the $k$ sixes. If $k\ge n-5$, the probability that the remaining $n-k$ dice contain no doubles is given by the above, with $6$ replaced by $5$ and $n$ replaced by $n-k$; whereas if $k\lt n-5$ there are at least $6$ dice that don’t show a six, and thus there is always a double. This yields the probability to get any doubles from $n$ dice other than sixes as

$$
1-6^{-n}\sum_{k=0\atop k\ge n-5}^n\binom nk\frac{5!}{(5-(n-k))!}\;.
$$